# How to convert accented text into plain text R

Tags: r, parsing, text, escaping

I'm parsing a text file from a French hydrological database that contains lines like this:

```
Date    Q (m3/s)    Validité    F. exp. Libellé Fréquence exp
```

When R reads these lines either with `read.csv` or `readLines`, the accents are escaped with codes to form this:

```
Date Q (m3/s) Validit\xe9 F. exp. Libell\xe9 Fr\xe9quence exp
```

These escape codes prevent simple grepl commands. So for example:

```
grepl("Date", "Date Q (m3/s) Validit\xe9 F. exp. Libell\xe9 Fr\xe9quence exp")
```

Produces the following result:

```
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In grepl("Date", "Date Q (m3/s) Validit\xe9 F. exp. Libell\xe9 Fr\xe9quence   exp") :
input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

What is the best way to deal with these escape codes so that I can apply simple text processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

`namc <- readLines(con <- file('g:/filename.txt', "r", encoding='UTF-8'))
close(con)
cat(namc)`

Remember to change the filename and path. You should be able to use `grepl` and `gsub` to clean it up after that